# Could not find or load main class, Swing

Tags: java, swing, program-entry-point

I am having a problem with my Java GUI application. It for some reason says that it cannot find or load the main class. I have checked all the brackets and don't see a problem. I had originally copied this over from another file as I wanted to start over with some things, maybe that is the problem. Here is the code:

```
public class GradeAverage extends JFrame {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JTextField textField;
    int numAverage = 0;
    double average;
    Container c;
    JLabel gradelbl;

    class AnswerHandler implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        
            numAverage++;
            gradelbl.setText("" + numAverage);
        }
    }

    public GradeAverage() {
        super("Final Grades");
        c = getContentPane();

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Grade: ");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(30, 50, 46, 14);


        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(81, 47, 86, 20);        
        textField.setColumns(10);



        JLabel gradeLbl = new JLabel("0");
        gradeLbl.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));
        gradeLbl.setBounds(91, 92, 15, 14);


        JLabel gradeTextLbl = new JLabel("Grades Recorded");
        gradeTextLbl.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));
        gradeTextLbl.setBounds(106, 92, 123, 14);


        JButton recordBtn = new JButton("Record");
        AnswerHandler ah = new AnswerHandler();
        recordBtn.addActionListener(ah);
        recordBtn.setBounds(177, 47, 86, 20);


        JButton displayAverageBtn = new JButton("New button");
        displayAverageBtn.setBounds(30, 117, 233, 23);


        JPanel finalGradePanel = new JPanel();
        finalGradePanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Enter Your Final Grades", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, new Color(0, 0, 128)));
        finalGradePanel.setBounds(10, 21, 264, 131);


        JPanel avgGradePanel = new JPanel();
        avgGradePanel.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 16));
        avgGradePanel.setBounds(10, 178, 264, 61);
        avgGradePanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Average Grade", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, new Color(0, 0, 128)));

        c.add(avgGradePanel);c.add(finalGradePanel);c.add(displayAverageBtn);c.add(recordBtn);c.add(gradeTextLbl);c.add(gradeLbl);  
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GradeAverage app = new GradeAverage();
        app.setSize(300, 300);
        app.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        app.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you start your program?

Comment: By pressing the run button in eclispe.

Comment: Works for me in Eclipse. I presume in Eclipse you are selecting the right main class called `GradeAverage`?

Comment: Yea I even tried clicking on the main on the right and running it from there, still get the same message

Comment: Its working. Open File in Eclipse -> Right click -> Run As -> Java Application

Comment: Perhaps clean your project first?